# Does someone encounter such an error: "Uncaught TypeError: t.mount is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

If open this error in the browser there is the next piece of code:

```
return this.isMounted&&n&&(t.mount(this.node),this._emitter.emit(A,t.node))
```

so the error on the **t.mount(this.node)**

It is minified React code. It's obvious that it does not tell nothing, so I went to build folder and searched for ".mount(" and it found the next piece of code in .app.js file:

```
symbol.mount(sprite.node)
```

which looks like the pice of code with the error.
I google for symbol.mount typeerror, but could extract any useful suggestion.

Maybe someone encounter something similar or have and idea what could it be?
Additional info: there is no error when project is run locally (even when built locally), only when deployed on the remote server..

Comment: What exactly is your setup and the problem you're having?

Comment: @junvar React project is build by webpack (what do you mean by setup?). The problem is that when I start it locally (by configured starting script) everything is ok – the app is rendered into the browser, but when I deploy it (by configured deployment script) there is the error in the browser and nothing is rendered (but build is successful in the bitbucket). So I'm asking for hint where to look for the possible problem (I know that it is all vague, not sure what details to give).